# Django: Removing unique constraint and creating migration

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have created a model and migrated in Django, with a unique key constraint for one of the field. Now am trying to remove the unique constraint and generate another migration file with the new change, but it says "Nothing seems to have changed".

I tried with the command 
**python manage.py schemamigration  --auto**

PS: I am using OnetoOne relationship for the field.

Comment: schemamigration is not a django command.

Comment: Django migrations should register any change in your model field parameters. What is the content of the generated migration files? You could delete the last file and try makemigrations again.

Comment: @HåkenLid Sorry that I forgot to mention that am using South for DB migration. schemamigration is a command available as part of South for generating migration files.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. A one to one relationship implies that one record is associated with another record uniquely. Even though the unique constraint is removed(for one to one field) in the code explicitly, it won't be reflected in your DB. So it won't create any migration file.

If you try the same thing for foreign constraint, it will work.

Comment: Thanks !!! It worked. I changed the OnetoOne relationship to Foreign and removed the unique key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I find the django automigration file generation problematic and incomplete.

Actually I experienced another similar problem with django migration just yesterday.

How I solved it:

- delete all migration files from the /migrations folder
- do a fresh makemigrations
- run `python manage.py migrate --fake` so django does not try to rebuild..
- Hey presto! Working and models updated :D

Comment: Thanks @talkingtoaj. I guess it will work out but I was looking for an option without making any other change in the field.